# custom 404 page for Rails 4

Tags: http-status-code-404, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make custom 404 page for Rails 4 app, but I can't find a working solution... 
Many people write solutions for Rails 3, but it's not working for Rails 4. Help me please.

I've created a controller "ErrorPages" with action "page_404".

Answer (score -1):

Templates for the error pages are in the `public` directory.
To customize the page for 404, you can simply edit the file called `404.html`.

Comment: How can I get a dynamic 404 page instead of a static one?